# I want to start making 2D Games with C++ or #C

Tags: xna, c++, c#, unity, sfml

I know C++ pretty well, I think - polymorphism, vectors, templates, and more.
I also know C#.

I want to program a 2D game, but not like those programs where you click a button or two, and you suddenly have a game running.

Though I feel pretty lost by googling.

I've found SFML for C++, though I had trouble finding a good tutorial on 2.0...

Then I searched for a C# one, and found Unity and XNA, though I'm not sure which one should fit my needs better.

So generally, I'm really confused and not sure how to start.

Btw, I'm open to other suggestions (like Java), and also I want to create at first very simple 2D games, like Tic Tac Toe and such, and move to more complicated one later.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please read the [FAQ] about where to get started questions. They're not a good fit for the site, since they don't work well with the Q/A format. You'll find a good resource for getting started in the [FAQ]. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For c++ there is SFML or SDL. SDL is my choice as i started with that one my self. 
To get started here is a good site for development : http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/index.php

In C# there is XNA, and there is tons of great tutorials for that aswell.
http://www.riemers.net/

It´s mostly up to you what you pick, but i'd go with XNA first and after a while when you got good beef on your legs, jump into C++.

- Unity is more of a engine rather than a framework. This will let you focus mainly on building your game, but i doubt you will have as much fun with unity than you will with C++/C#.

Comment: Wow, even though Im in the wrong place, thank you very very much!